# Split one row into two

Tags: r, split, row

I would like to obtain to split each row of a dataframe into two. That´s my input:

```
input <- 'name sample1 sample2 sample3
              pr_001  533  411    633
              pr_002  478  447  427'  
input <- read.table(text=input, header=T)
```

To obtain this output:

```
output <- 'name sample1 sample2 sample3
              pr_001-A  533  411    633
              pr_001-B  533  411   633
              pr_002-A  478  447  427  
              pr_002-B  478  447  427'
 output <- read.table(text=output, header=T)
```

Thus, for `pr_001` in `sample1` the result is a two rows with the same value `pr_001-A` and `pr_001-A`, and the same logic must be follow for all samples and names. Some idea to deal with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First duplicate the rows with (based on [akrun's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923445/split-one-row-into-two/32923486#comment53673550_32923445)):

```
output <- input[rep(1:nrow(input), each = 2),]
```

Then add the `-A` and `-B` to each `name` with:

```
output$name <- paste(output$name, c("A", "B"), sep = "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(input %>% 
            mutate(sample1 = paste(sample1, "A", sep = "-"),
          input %>% 
            mutate(sample1 = paste(sample1, "B", sep = "-") ) %>%
  arrange(sample1)
```

Comment: A hint. Because you are adding no explanatory text or showing that they actually work, these are all getting flagged as low quality and we have to review them and decide whether or not do delete them in the review queue. It is very tedious, and I have seen 4 of your posts in the last 10 minutes. Please try harder to produce an obviously high quality answer.